Dynamic refresh and access token updating. ASP.NET Core 8
I want to update my access and refresh tokens in my backend using middleware. When I send a request to my API, I take the token from the context and add it to the authorization header.
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    opt =>
    {
        opt.SaveToken = true;
        opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["TokenSettings:Secret"]!)),
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = configuration["TokenSettings:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = configuration["TokenSettings:Audience"],
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name
        };
        opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                context.Token = context.Request.Cookies[configuration["TokenSettings:CookieName"]!];
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

I want to implement a refresh token system, and when I get a 401 error, I want to obtain new access and refresh tokens and continue sending the same request. Here is my RefreshTokenMiddleware:
public sealed class RefreshTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate Next, IOptions<TokenSetting> TokenSettings)
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next = Next;
    private readonly TokenSetting _tokenSettings = TokenSettings.Value;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            var refreshToken = context.Request.Cookies[_tokenSettings.RefreshCookieName];
            if (refreshToken is not null)
            {
                var tokenService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>();
                var tokenResult = await tokenService.GenerateTokenFromRefreshToken(refreshToken);

                if (tokenResult.IsSuccess)
                {
                    context.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {tokenResult.Value}";
                    await _next(context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

My TokenService:
using Application.Services.TokenService;

namespace Infrastructure.Services.TokenService
{
    public sealed class TokenService(
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
        IOptions<TokenSetting> tokenSettings) : ITokenService
    {
        private readonly HttpContext _context = contextAccessor.HttpContext!;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        private readonly TokenSetting _tokenSettings = tokenSettings?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenSettings));


        public async Task<Result<string>> GenerateToken(AppUser user, IList<string> roles)
        {
            if (user == null) return Result<string>.Failure(Error.BadRequest(UserTaskErrors.UserTaskNotFound));
            if (roles == null) return Result<string>.Failure(Error.BadRequest(TokenErrors.InvalidRole));

            var claims = GetClaims(user, roles);
            var token = CreateJwtToken(claims);
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var addClaimsResult = await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);
            if (!addClaimsResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return Result<string>.Failure(Error.InvalidRequest(TokenErrors.FailedToAddClaim));
            }
            string accessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            AppendCookie(accessToken);
            await GenerateRefreshToken(user);
            return Result<string>.Success(accessToken);
        }

        public async Task<Result<string>> GenerateRefreshToken(AppUser user)
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[32];
            using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            
            string uniqueData = $"{user.Id}-{user.Email}-{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
            byte[] uniqueBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uniqueData);
            
            byte[] combinedBytes = randomNumber.Concat(uniqueBytes).ToArray();
            
            using var sha256 = SHA256.Create();
            byte[] hashBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(combinedBytes);
            
            string refreshToken = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
            
            await _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Id == user.Id)
                .ExecuteUpdateAsync(x => x.SetProperty(u => u.RefreshToken, refreshToken));
            
            AppendCookie(refreshToken, true);
            return Result<string>.Success(refreshToken);
        }

        public Result<ClaimsPrincipal> GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(string token)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tokenSettings.Secret)),
                    ValidateLifetime = false
                };

                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out var securityToken);
                var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;

                if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return Result<ClaimsPrincipal>.Failure(Error.InvalidRequest(TokenErrors.InvalidToken));
                }

                return Result<ClaimsPrincipal>.Success(principal);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Result<ClaimsPrincipal>.Failure(Error.InvalidRequest(TokenErrors.InvalidToken));
            }
        }

        public async Task<Result<string>> GenerateTokenFromRefreshToken(string refreshToken)
        {
            var user = await ValidateRefreshToken(refreshToken);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Result<string>.Failure(Error.InvalidRequest(TokenErrors.InvalidRefreshToken));
            }

            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var result = await GenerateToken(user, roles);
            if (result.IsFailure)
            {
                return Result<string>.Failure(result.Error);
            }
            return Result<string>.Success(result.Value);
        }

        private List<Claim> GetClaims(AppUser user, IList<string> roles)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim("UserId", user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email!),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName!)
            };

            claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));
            return claims;
        }

        private JwtSecurityToken CreateJwtToken(List<Claim> claims)
        {
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_tokenSettings.Secret));
            return new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _tokenSettings.Issuer,
                audience: _tokenSettings.Audience,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(_tokenSettings.Expiration),
                claims: claims,
                
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );
        }

        private void AppendCookie(string token, bool isRefresh = false)
        {
            if (!isRefresh)
            {
                CookieOptions option = new()
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_tokenSettings.Expiration),
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                    Secure = true
                };
                _context?.Response.Cookies.Append(_tokenSettings.CookieName, token, option);
                return;
            }

            CookieOptions refreshTokenOption = new()
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(_tokenSettings.ExpirationRefresh),
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                Secure = true
            };
            _context?.Response.Cookies.Append(_tokenSettings.RefreshCookieName, token, refreshTokenOption);
        }

        private async Task<AppUser?> ValidateRefreshToken(string refreshToken)
        {
            return await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.RefreshToken == refreshToken);
        }
    }
}

My problem is that when my access token expires and I get a 401 error, I can create and store new tokens, but I still get a 401 error again. I need to resend the request to get a 200 response.
Finding the problem why I get the 401 after updating the my tokens and store them moreover if something is wrong why I get 200 resend it.

Minimal reproducible example
TokenService
public sealed class TokenService(
    IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : ITokenService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;

    public async Task<string> CreateAccess()
    {
        //I create access and refresh token and store them in the cookies of response
        _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", "access_token");
        await CreateRefresh();
        //I return it because I use it in the middleware for sending request but normally I never return it
        return "access_token";
    }

    public Task<string> CreateRefresh()
    {
        _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Response.Cookies.Append("refresh_token", "refresh_token");
        //Add refresh token to database AppUser refreshToken column
        return Task.FromResult("refresh_token");
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateTokenFromRefreshToken(string refreshToken)
    {
        //Check refresh token is correct in database AppUser refreshToken column
        // If correct, generate new access token and refresh token
        var acc = await CreateAccess();
        //when I create the access and refresh they are stored in the cookies of response also
        return acc;
    }
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("Bearer",
            opt =>
            {
                opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    // When I get request I take the cookies and put them in the token
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["access_token"];
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

RefreshTokenMiddleware
public sealed class RefreshTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate Next)
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next = Next;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            var refreshToken = context.Request.Cookies["refresh_token"];
            if (refreshToken is not null)
            {
                var tokenService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>();
                //store new access and refresh token in the cookies of response
                var tokenResult = await tokenService.GenerateTokenFromRefreshToken(refreshToken);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenResult))
                {
                    //they works well but the requet return the 401 status code when I send the request again after I got 401 it gives me 200 that means token genereated and stored correctly but my middleware request cant send the request again
                    context.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {tokenResult}";
                    await _next(context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I also use await  context.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
to authenticate again, but it didn't work either.

I cannot reproduce the issue. Could you kindly provide a proper minimal reproducible example of this issue?

I added it and tried to keep it simple by deleting everything to make it more understandable.
